# support for ubuntu bash in windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was just curious, is there any support forums for ubuntu bash?

I just downloaded bash on my windows laptop and I'd be grateful if someone pointed me to forums where I can get my questions answered.

Regards,
SUnil

Comment: Probably best to ask on Ask Ubuntu - http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This place should help you for any further questions:

https://github.com/microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues

And this page would tell you about what's working and what not:

https://github.com/ethanhs/WSL-Programs